# Why can't have control with ID "Server"

Tags: asp.net

I had this line in my page:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="Server" />
```

And I was getting the following error:

> Compiler Error Message: CS1061: 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox' does not contain a definition for 'ScriptTimeout' and no extension method 'ScriptTimeout' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>
> Source Error:

```
Line 172:                global::ASP.applications_returndata_releasemanagement_aspx.@__initialized = true;
Line 173:            }
Line 174:            this.Server.ScriptTimeout = 30000000;
Line 175:        }
Line 176:
```

After changing the ID to something else it was fine.

Does anyone know why you can't use "Server" as control ID? I searched and I couldn't find anything about reserved words for asp.net controls.

Comment: It is because `Server` is a property of the page

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because `System.Web.UI.Page` has already a field called `Server` (You can see it when you navigate to the class definition of `System.Web.UI.Page`).

Answer (score 5):

`Server` is one of a number of predefined properties in the base class of any ASP.Net page - this list also includes `Response`, `Request`, etc.

By calling your own control `Server`, you are overriding the default properties and rendering meaningless certain .Net calls including, in this case, `Server.ScriptTimeout`.